# interchanges/transpositions (how to read)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry

I have came across this before and just again now, in the same form of which I'm struggling to understand.
Although I know it's link to parity, as a perm group pi:

$$ \pi = \begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & n \\ a_{0} & a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} & \dots &a_{n} \end{pmatrix}$$

$$ (-1)^{\pi} = \prod^{n}_{j}f(x_{j+1}) - f(x_{j})$$

There are repeatedly questions as such:

**Example**

Consider the composition (12)(23) of the two cycle (12) in the set $S_3$, and the 2-cycle (23) in $S_3$.

The number 1 is mapped to itself by (23) and then to 2 by (12).
The number 2 is mapped to 3 by (23), which is mapped to itself by (12)
The number 3 is mapped to 2 by (23), which is mapped to itself by (12).
So overall, 1 maps to 2, which maps to 3, which maps to 1, or:

(12)(23) = (123)

How did he make those assumptions? I have cycled through the Levi-Civita tensor before however I can't see these exact mappings.

Comment: It is difficult to tell exactly what you are asking, and what it is that you do not understand. The example seems very straightforward. What is the first statement in your example that you do not understand? And what do you mean by "How did he make those assumptions"? What assumptions? Your final sentence does not seem to relate to anything else!

Comment: The formula for $\left(-1\right)^\pi$ looks like nonsense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking why $(12)(23)=(123)$ ?

$(i,j)$ means a transposition which makes 
$\pi = \begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & i & \dots & j & \dots & n \\ a_{0} & a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} & \dots & a_{i} & \dots & a_{j} & \dots  &a_{n} \end{pmatrix}$
into $\pi = \begin{pmatrix}  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & i & \dots & j & \dots & n \\ a_{0} & a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} & \dots & a_{j} & \dots & a_{i} & \dots  &a_{n} \end{pmatrix}$

i.e  $(a_{i},a_{j})$ changes to $(a_{j},a_{i})$ here.

and $(i,j,k)$ is a three cycle i.e  $(i->j->k->i)$ which basically maps $(a_{i}, a_{j},a_{k})$ into $(a_{j}, a_{k},a_{i})$ .

Now why $(i,j)(j,k)=(i,j,k)$ ?

For that apply $ \pi_{1} = (j,k)$ on $ \pi_{2} = (i,j)$ and check it by yourself that $\pi = (i,j,k)$ = $ \pi_{2}o\pi_{1}$ . (function composition).
This would extend for general case for n transpositions or cycles.
Also remember the following easy to handle formulations :

1. $(a_{1}a_{2} \dots a_{n})$ = $(a_{2} \dots a_{n}a_{1})$
2. $(a_{1}a_{2} \dots a_{n})$ = $(a_{1}a_{2})(a_{2}a_{3}) \dots (a_{n-1}a_{n})$

Hope I could clarify.

Comment: Could you explicitly show why $$(i,j) $$ multiplied with $$ (j,k) $$ is $$ (i,j,k)$$. I have tried and cannot get it, the closest I got was $$ (i, 2j, k) $$ with the tensor product.

Comment: multiplication here means you apply the $(i,j)$ on the $(j,k)$

Comment: Hey check I've added a bit more.